# Solve limit with Lagrange theorem

Tags: limits

I tried to solve this limit:
$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} x^2\left(e^{\frac{1}{x+1}}-e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right) $$

Instead of solving it with Taylor series (using $u = 1/x$), I noticed that the difference within the parenthesis is the $\Delta f$ of the function $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

> $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x^2 * \Delta\left(e^{1/x}\right) = $
>
> The Lagrange theorem says that $\Delta f = D\left[f\right] * \Delta x$, so
>
> $=\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x^2 * \left( D\left[e^{1/x}\right]_{x_0} * \Delta x\right), x_0 \in \left(x, x+1\right)$
>
> $$ x_0=x+r(x)$$ 
>   $$ 0<r(x)<1 $$
>
> $=\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x^2 * \left( e^{\frac{1}{x+r(x)}} * \left(-\frac{1}{\left(x+r(x)\right)^2}\right)\right) $
>
> $=\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} -\frac{1}{\left(x+r(x)\right)^2} * x^2 * e^{\frac{1}{x+r(x)}}$
>
> $\approx \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} -\frac{1}{x^2} * x^2 * e^{\frac{1}{x}} $
>
> $=\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} -1 * e^{\frac{1}{x}} = -1$

Is it correct to proceed in this way?

EDIT: Using approximations is not a very elegant solution. I might be more precise using the Squeeze theorem (I'll think the solution, then I'll post it)

Instead of using the approximation, we consider these three functions:

- $f(x) = x^2 * e^{\frac{1}{x+1}} * \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$
- $h(x) = x^2 * e^{\frac{1}{x+r(x)}} * \frac{1}{(x+r(x))^2}$
- $g(x) = x^2 * e^{\frac{1}{x}} * \frac{1}{x^2}$

Obviously, $f(x) \le h(x) \le g(x)$ for $x > 0$ and $r(x) \in (0, 1)$.

> $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x^2 * e^{\frac{1}{x+1}} * \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} = 1$
>
> (It is 1 and not -1 just because I left the minus sign out of the limit)
>
> $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} g(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x^2 * e^{\frac{1}{x}} * \frac{1}{x^2} = 1$

So $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} h(x) = 1 \rightarrow \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} -h(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x^2\left(e^{\frac{1}{x+1}}-e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right) = -1$

Here's how the f (the red function) and g (the blue function) look like:

[image]

Comment: Taylor expansion gives $f(x)=-1-1/(6x^3)+o(1/x^3)$ in the neighbourhood of $+\infty$

Answer (score 2):

We can also proceed in the following manner
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to \infty}x^{2}\{e^{1/(x + 1)} - e^{1/x}\}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}x^{2}e^{1/x}\{e^{1/(x + 1) - 1/x} - 1\}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}x^{2}e^{1/x}\cdot\frac{e^{1/(x + 1) - 1/x} - 1}{1/(x + 1) - 1/x}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{x + 1} - \frac{1}{x}\right)\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{2}e^{1/x}\cdot 1\cdot\frac{1}{x(x + 1)}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to \infty}1\cdot\frac{x}{x + 1}\notag\\
&= -\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{x}}\notag\\
&= -1\notag
\end{align}
Your approach starts off correctly, but there is a problem in the middle when you use $\approx$ symbol. A limit evaluation is an exact operation and not an approximate one. But this is a minor error and you can just say that $e^{1/(x + r(x))} \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ and the ratio $x^{2}/(x + r(x))^{2} \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ (I hope you can justify easily why both these limits should be $1$).

Comment: Great solution. I think my solution is incomplete, it might be justifyed with the "Squeeze" theorem. Do you agree?

Comment: @claudia: yes you need to use the Squeeze theorem on inequalities like $e^{1/(x + 1)} < e^{1/(x + r(x))} < e^{1/x}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^2 \left( e^{\frac{1}{x+1}} -e^{\frac{1}{x}} \right)\\
= & \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{2 (x+1)^2} + O(x^{-3}) - 1 -\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2 x^2} + O(x^{-3})\right) \\
= & \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-x^2}{(x+1)x} + \frac{-2x-1}{2(x+1)^2 x^2} +O(x^{-1})
= -1.
\end{align}

Comment: In case that  OP would like to use the series expansion of $e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume throughout that $x>0$.

By Lagrange’s theorem, you can write
$$
\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{(x+1)-x}=f'(c_x)
$$
for some $c_x\in (x,x+1)$. Thus
$$
x^2(f(x+1)-f(x))=x^2f'(c_x)=-\frac{x^2}{c_x^2}f(c_x)
$$
Now
$$
f(x+1)\le f(c_x)\le f(x),\qquad
x^2\le c_x^2\le (x+1)^2
$$
and putting the inequalities together
$$
\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}f(x+1)\le \frac{x^2}{c_x^2}f(c_x)\le 
f(x)
$$
that can be rewritten as
$$
-f(x)\le x^2(f(x+1)-f(x))\le -\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}f(x+1)
$$
Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$ we conclude by the squeeze theorem that your limit is $-1$.